# Visual Studio Debugger doesnt step into unused variable declarations

Tags: c#, debugging

The debugger does not want to step into an unused variable. If I declare `(var x = "hola")` it doesn't recognize `x` and says that it doesn't exist in the current context. When I do some work with `x` then it recognizes it.

Comment: Is that in Release or Debug mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That line of code is probably optimized away by the compiler...
You might be able to step into it if you turn off optimizations.

Comment: Yeah that was the solution!, but i didnt remember have turned on that option, is not by default always selected optimize code? well is working now thanks.

Comment: It's on by default in Release builds, off in Debug builds. Not sure if VS Express supports this distinction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199204/how-can-i-disable-compiler-optimization-in-c