# Using MVC .NET Core 2 as a server for WebClient calls from .NET 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, webclient, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my fist MVC app in .net core, so be easy on me, please.

I have been trying to use my new mvc app as a RestAPI.
Have a following case:

[image]

I am wondering, why does my debugger jump over the three yellow lines which have something to do with the service?

[image]

My DataService has a scoped lifetime.

By normal web requests, DataService runs normally, however, it seems that when using WebClient from an app on 4.52 framework, this wierd behaviour starts to show.

All I get returned is Http errorcode 500.
If I use just return Content(string.Empty,..), or some other string, I get 200. 
So, it is definitely something about how the service is instatiated, but I am not sure where to look, and what to change in order to make this work.

Comment: never add pictures of codes, include codes.

Comment: Make sure that you are not debugging with the `Optimize Code` setting enabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1199204/1220550

Comment: Thank you Peter B.
A lifesaver!