# Disable Optimizations in a 3rd party .NET Core DLL

Tags: .net-core

With .NET Framework DLLs, it is possible to disable optimizations using an .INI file with this contents, and the name matching the assembly followed by `.ini`:

```
[.NET Framework Debugging Control] 
GenerateTrackingInfo=1 
AllowOptimize=0
```

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899739/402949)

I've tried that approach with a .NET Core app, and it doesn't work, which is not surprising since the syntax  references ".NET Framework". Is there a similar method for disabling optimizations for a 3rd party .NET Core DLL?

Comment: In the source code, I found an enum `System.Reflection.AssemblyFlags`, with values `DisableJitCompileOptimizer` and `EnableJitCompileTracking`. These seem to correspond to the two Framework settings you posted. I cannot immediately figure out where to set those flags, though. (In a [project props file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601178/7711863)?)